# curl login and post again in member area

Tags: php, curl

I am making an automated login to a member area using curl and it's successful but after the login I want to post a form inside the member area but I don't know how to do that, can you help me please, my current code as follows...

```
$main_url = 'https://www.url.com';

$redirect = '/reports/marks-checker';
$email =    'user@gmail.com'; 
$password = 'pass123'; 


$url= $main_url.'/account/login'; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$postdata = 'redirect='.$redirect.'&EmailAddress='.$email.'&Password='.$password.'&RememberMe=1'; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 
echo $result;

curl_close($ch);
```

above code prints(echo) member area and form(given below) which i want to query...

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="radio" name="IDS" value="F" checked/>
<input type="radio" name="IDS" value="H"/>
<textarea name="q" cols="80" rows="15" wrap="none" style="width:99%"></textarea>
<select name="SortBy">
    <option value="0">rank</option>
    <option value="1">date</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="getmarks" value="Check marks"/>
</form>
```

I want to post data to this form and get results back so i could grab the data using regex. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use either DOM functions or regular expressions or prior knowledge of the form (whatever is applicable in your situation) to create an array of the form variables and the values you want to assign them:

```
    $form_vars = array();
```

with the name/value pairs IDS/F or H, q/some text, SortBy/0 or 1.

```
    $form_vars[$var_name] = $value;
```

e.g.

```
    $form_vars['IDS'] = "H";
```

Then use the http_build_query function to build your query:

```
    $encoded_form_vars = http_build_query($form_vars);
```

Then try something like this:

```
    function postForm($url, $fields, $referer='') {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Expect:"));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
            return curl_exec($ch);
    }
```

called with something like this:

```
    $result = postForm($url, $encoded_form_vars);
```